# Polymer how to include svg file in an icon?

Tags: html, css, svg, polymer

I am newbie to polymer want to use svg file as icon. 
Is there any way to use like ?

```
<core-icon src="icon/test.svg"></core-icon>
```

instead of

```
<core-iconset-svg id="my-svg-icons" iconSize="24">
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <g id="shape">
        <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
      </g>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</core-iconset-svg>
```

Comment: See https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/icons.html

Answer (score 1):

Definitely check out [Rob's Polycast video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrt7sMq9lO0) and the documentation listed here - `https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/icons.html` (as suggested in the comment by [Erik Dahlström](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109374/erik-dahlstr%c3%b6m) ) .

Also I believe you may need a leading forward slash for custom svgs but I am not 100% on that.